# SQL Server crashes after Update via OpenQuery to Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server, openquery

I tried to update our Oracle Database via SQL Server. This is my SQL Statement:

```
Update OPENQUERY(DB, 'select t$clot from table 
where table.t$oorg=''50'' 
and table.t$orno between ''200294438'' and ''200294439'' 
and table.t$clot = ''120''') 
set t$clot = ' ';
```

This statement runs, it changes the values in oracle. But running another statement (Select or Update) afterwards crashes the SQL server on which this statements are executed.
Sometimes I could run 1-2 Updates before it crashed.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Do I need to commit or end transaction or something?

Comment: Crashes the _server_?  What version/patchlevel are you running?

Comment: @user1443098 I tried it on  Miccrosoft SQL Server (2014) 12.0.5632.1 and (2016) 13.0.5337.0 - both with the same result. I had to restart the database server via the management studio after the update command.